# IBM MQ .NET Client - how to define selectors on a queue

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I want to read/get only some messages from a queue, based on some properties specified in the selector but I can't find the way to set the selector. Where should it be set? Should it be set in the AccesQueue method of the MQueueManager class?

I'm using amqmdnet.dll as MQ Client.

```
MQQueueManager manager = new MQQueueManager( settings.QueueManager, connectionSettings );

MQQueue queue = manager.AccessQueue( ToQueueName, openOptions );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to process all of the messages in the queue but if you want to go down that path then you need to use the MQ XMS .NET layer.  Here is a starting point: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024064